# 配列の添字の型は何？ int ? size_t?

Tags: c++, c

C/C++の非常に素朴な疑問です。

> a[ i ] の i の型は何か?

です。
古き良きK&R時代であればintでしょうが、いつからか、sizeof演算子の戻り値もsize_tなので
size_tではないのか？という疑問がわきます。

とはいえ、(ちょっと強引なコードですが)

```
const char *a = "abcdefg";
a++;
printf("%c", a[-1]);
```

もありなので、-1を指定できるということはint?

C++コンテナの`operator [](...)`は添字の型が定義されているから
それ(たいてい size_type)に従えばよいのですが、

単純な配列型(`char []`など)の添字の型はなんでしょうか？

Comment: 意外な書き方が出来るので参考までに
http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/14585/
括弧の中に配列を書いちゃうこともできるのです。

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ｃについてですが、

配列の宣言と使用の２種類があると思いますが、

C11 の[ドラフト](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) の
**6.7.6.2 Array declarators**

> 1 In addition to optional type qualifiers and the keyword static, the
>   [ and ] may delimit an expression or *. If they delimit an expression
>   (which specifies the size of an array), the expression shall have an
>   integer type. If the expression is a constant expression, it shall
>   have a value greater than zero. The element type shall not be an
>   incomplete or function type. The optional type qualifiers and the
>   keyword static shall appear only in a declaration of a function
>   parameter with an array type, and then only in the outermost array
>   type derivation.

the expression shall have **an integer type**. If the expression is a constant expression, it shall have **a value greater than zero**.
とありますから

「整数型で０より大きい値」ということになると思います。
（**int**のみ(`char a[10];`←この場合はリテラルの１０はint)というわけではなく例えば`static char a[10000ULL];`などもＯＫです）

---

配列としてのアクセスについては、
**6.5.2.1 Array subscripting**

> 2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets []
>   is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The
>   definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to
>   (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
>   binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer
>   to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer,
>   E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero).

**E2 is an integer**
とありますからこちらも整数型（こちらはマイナス可、（結果は配列の範囲内である必要があります（アドレスとしては最後の次のアドレスは有効、この場合は読み書きはできない）））ですね。

Answer (score 1):

C++に関しては、`std::ptrdiff_t`ですね。この型が実際に何になるかは実装依存ですが、符号付き整数になります。

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t から引用

> std::ptrdiff_t is used for pointer arithmetic and array indexing, if negative values are possible.

ついでに、ちょっと古いドラフトですが、こちらかも引用。
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf

> For every cv-qualified or cv-unqualified object type T there exist candidate operator functions of the form
>      T * operator+(T *, std::ptrdiff_t);
>      T & operator[](T *, std::ptrdiff_t);
>      T * operator-(T *, std::ptrdiff_t);
>      T * operator+(std::ptrdiff_t, T *);
>      T & operator[](std::ptrdiff_t, T *);

Comment: Cについても同じではないでしょうか？
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/ptrdiff_tから引用。'ptrdiff_t is used for pointer arithmetic and array indexing'

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t には、`size_t is commonly used for array indexing`とも書いてあります。

Comment: 該当サイトの説明は「演算子`[]`にて`ptrdiff_t`や`size_t`を利用できる」と言っているだけで、添え字の型が`ptrdiff_t` **である** とはなっていません。

Comment: ちょっと古いドラフトですが、仕様で`operator[]`について述べている部分の引用を追加しました。

Comment: 同セクションの第1パラグラフに "These candidate functions **participate in the operator overload resolution process** as described in 13.3.1.2 and **are used for no other purpose**" とあり、これを根拠に`ptrdiff_t`型というのは少々厳しいかもしれませんね。

Comment: オーバーロードの解決に使われるということは、この型にあった呼び出しを行うと組み込みの実装（ポインタ演算）が行われるという意味ですから、正にこの組み込みの実装の引数の型が`ptrdiff_tであるということだと思うのですが、それ以上何をお望みでしょうか?